# JVM Terminated in opening eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, fedora

I'm using fedora 18. I want to open eclipse, but get errors as below:

```
    JVM terminated. Exit code=13
    /usr/bin/java
    -Xms128m
    -Xmx512m
    -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true
    -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode,forwardDeltaWith
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding,<init>
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/semantics/CPPTemplates,instantiateTemplate
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/pdom/dom/cpp/PDOMCPPLinkage,addBinding
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/editor/codecompletion/revisited/PythonPathHelper,isValidSourceFile
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/ui/filetypes/FileTypesPreferencesPage,getDottedValidSourceFiles
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/tycho/core/osgitools/EquinoxResolver,newState
    -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
    -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    -jar /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130701-1300.jar
    -os linux
    -ws gtk
    -arch x86_64
    -showsplash /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v20130701-1255/splash.bmp
    -launcher /usr/lib64/eclipse/eclipse
    -name Eclipse
    --launcher.library /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130701-1300/eclipse_1503.so
```

After inputting

```
 echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I get
    /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31

```
 uname -r
 3.10.10-100.fc18.x86_64
```

the content of eclipse.ini:

```
    -preventMasterEclipseLaunch
    -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130701-1300.jar
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130701-1300
    -showsplash
    org.eclipse.platform
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256m
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    -vmargs
    -Xms128m
    -Xmx512m

    -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true
    -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode,forwardDeltaWith
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding,<init>
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/semantics/CPPTemplates,instantiateTemplate
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/pdom/dom/cpp/PDOMCPPLinkage,addBinding
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/editor/codecompletion/revisited/PythonPathHelper,isValidSourceFile
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/ui/filetypes/FileTypesPreferencesPage,getDottedValidSourceFiles
    -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/tycho/core/osgitools/EquinoxResolver,newState
    -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
```

it seems the jvm is 64bit, compatible with my linux machine?

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you added JAVA_HOME in environment file?
please try with 64bit eclipse if you have installed 64 bit fedora?

Comment: @GreySwordz seems it is different from my situation, coz I'm using linux